# How to get Json object values inside array in angular using ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, json

I have a array of JSON objects like below:

```
 todoList:
      [ { todo: 'dummy1', id: 595b9c2bb4b9992a4041d6e3 },
      { todo: 'dummy2', id: 595e4ffc62e38e3844f8d43a },
      { todo: 'dummy3', id: 595e4fff62e38e3844f8d43b },
      { todo: 'dummy4', id: 595f00c1d18df61840ad1ba3 } ]
```

I want to use the todo field in my view using ng-repeat like below

```
<div ng-repeat ="todo in todoList">
  <label>
     {{ todo }}
   </label>
 </div>
```

Can you please tell me the way in which I can access only todo field from the todo List?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
<div ng-repeat ="todo in todoList">
  <label>
     {{ todo.todo }}
   </label>
  <label>
     {{ todo.id}}
   </label>
 </div>
```

If you want to debug, You can use json filter to print json object.

```
<div ng-repeat ="todo in todoList">
  <label>
     {{ todo|json}}
   </label>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **`{{todo.todo}}`**

```
<div ng-repeat ="todo in todoList">
  <label>
     {{ todo.todo}}
   </label>
 </div>
```

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
 $scope.todoList=
      [ { todo: 'dummy1', id: "595b9c2bb4b9992a4041d6e3" },
      { todo: 'dummy2', id: "595e4ffc62e38e3844f8d43a" },
      { todo: 'dummy3', id: "595e4fff62e38e3844f8d43b" },
      { todo: 'dummy4', id: "595f00c1d18df61840ad1ba3" } ];
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
</head>

<body>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
 <div ng-repeat ="todo in todoList">
  <label>
     {{ todo.todo }}
   </label>
 </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here todo become one object from todoList object, then you can access property from that, like todo.todo and todo.id

```
<div ng-repeat ="todo in todoList">
 <label>
  {{ todo.todo }}
 </label>
</div>
```